# How to get MethodInfo from FSharpFunc object via Reflection?

Tags: .net, reflection, f#

We know in C#, you can get the `MethodInfo` and the closure instance `Target` through the properties of `Delegate` type. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate(v=vs.110).aspx).

Now the question is, if we get an `FSharpFunc` object, how can we get those reflection information?

Comment: `FSharpFunc` does not necessarily point to a method, so there is not always a `MethodInfo` associated with it. Why do you need it?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I think in IL level, it is a method, either static or instance method. The reason is, I want to get the IL instruction for that FSharpFunc.

Comment: Just get the `Invoke` method (just like a delegate...)

Comment: @leppie, the `Invoke` method of `FSharpFunc` is a virtual function, it is not the real method. I don't need to call that virtual function, instead, I want to find the `MethodInfo` of that real implementation method.

Comment: You would need the instance for that.